# Which machine learning methods can I use to predict DNA Sequences?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, predict, dna-sequence

I have a dataset of DNA Sequences related to Covid-19 and I simply want to predict possible future sequences based on the existing sequences.

DNA Sequences are consist of 4 letters and 4 letters only, A,G,T and C. So a chunk of a sequence would look like

"ATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAA"

Any advice or help regarding how to predict future mutations based on these existing data would be a lot of help.

Comment: If you don't have a fairly large dataset of past mutations (thousands of samples), it would be very hard to do anything

Comment: I have a dataset of 20 Million entries, I have cleansed and filtered only hundred thousand entries as my sample dataset, I hope that would be enough?

Comment: Then any sequential model (e.g. from text generation) would do. Obraining the very best results would require lots of reserach though, if you need one, you'd better start searching which methods are more common in DNA sequencing via ML